# Trouble with a VBA Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am running a loop that is modifying copied data and scanning for unnecessary rows. I think the code is really close but I must have something out of place here:

```
Dim DeleteRowData As Long
Dim DeleteRowCounter As Long
DeleteRowData = Cells(Rows.Count, 3)


Set DataSheet = Sheets("Class Data")
Set TransType = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.[C1], DataSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
For DeleteRowCounter = DeleteRowData To 1 Step -1
If Cells(DeleteRowCounter, 3) = "TYP" Then
Rows(DeleteRowCounter).Delete
End If
Next
```

What is happening currently is that the macro is skipping this section of code even when there are lines that have "TYP" in column C

```
If Cells(DeleteRowCounter, 3) = "TYP" Then
Rows(DeleteRowCounter).Delete
End If
```

Can someone help me correct this?

Comment: You really should specify the parent `Worksheet` for `Cells` and `Rows`. Do you mean `DataSheet.Cells` and `DataSheet.Rows`?

Comment: `DeleteRowData = Cells(Rows.Count, 3)` ... this pulls the value from the very last row in column C on the active sheet, which is likely an empty cell.

Comment: That was just to bring the data filtering sheet to the forefront. I dont think I have it running the most efficiently, but to get my mind around it, I had to set different key functions happen in different sheets. 

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: if code is in a module rather than a sheet, it is best to always qualify `Range` and `Cells` with a worksheet qualifier.  That's not necessarily the problem here, but just a tip about vba programming - but it COULD be the problem (you could be deleting things on the wrong sheet!).

Comment: As pointed out by BigBen - `DeleteRowData = Cells(Rows.Count, 3)` this is not going to give you a row number, it is the actual value inside the cell. So it is not doing what you expect when you use it here: `DeleteRowData To 1 Step -1` In general, this code seems to be convoluted - not really focused on what it needs to do and only what it needs to do - too much noise. `TransType` is not even used at all. Indentation is missing. Using `With` will help it be more clear, less noisy too. BigBen's example is much more "typical" vba for a task of this kind.

Comment: Note: some basic debugging will answer many of your questions for you (learning to fish blah blah). This link is an oldy but a goody: [excel-vba-debugging](https://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/programming-excel-vba-debugging-for.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This doesn't find the last row correctly:

   ```
   DeleteRowData = Cells(Rows.Count, 3)
   ```

   This returns the *value* of the very last cell in column C on the active sheet. That cell is likely empty, making `DeleteRowData` equal to `0`. Therefore the loop never runs.
2. Specify the parent `Worksheet` for all `Rows` and `Cells` calls.

   ```
   Dim DeleteRowData As Long
   Dim DeleteRowCounter As Long

   Set DataSheet = Sheets("Class Data")
   With DataSheet
        DeleteRowData = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

        For DeleteRowCounter = DeleteRowData To 1 Step -1
             If .Cells(DeleteRowCounter, 3).Value = "TYP" Then
                 .Rows(DeleteRowCounter).Delete
             End iF
        Next
    End With
   ```

3. If "contains" means that `TYP` is part (but not necessarily all) of the cell content, then replace

   ```
   If .Cells(DeleteRowCounter, 3).Value = "TYP" Then
   ```

   with

   ```
   If InStr(.Cells(DeleteRowCounter, 3).Value, "TYP") > 0 Then
   ```

   or

   ```
   If .Cells(DeleteRowCounter, 3).Value Like "*TYP*"
   ```

Comment: I tried this and the code ran and I could tell it went through each row of data but it did not delete any of the rows that had "TYP" in the 3rd column.

Comment: This checks if their value is exactly "TYP". Likely your cells contain TYP and something else (whitespace, other letters).